# Value not shown in a card in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to return the total sales value in a card in Plotly Dash. The code I have written in the callback to return value is as follows:

```
@app.callback(
Output('card_1', 'children' ),
Output('card_2', 'children' ),
Output('card_3', 'children' ),
Output('card_4', 'children' ),
Output('card_5', 'children' ),


Input("dropdown", "value"),
Input("dropdown2", "value"))

def update_card(year, month):
df=df1.copy()
df= df[(df['Year']== year) & (df1['Month'] == month)]
total_sales = df['Total'].sum()
total= int(total_sales)
return total
```

The error Dash is giving is that the return value should be in class tuple or class list. I have tried to change the int value to list, but then it gives error that the the int value is not iterable. Can anyone please tell me how can I display this value in the card?

Answer (score 1):

So, I did not call the other card values, which is why it was giving me that particular error. If you want to return multiple outputs, you have to specify each in the return.